# catch activity not found exception in a pendingIntent.getActivity

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have a pending intent for a notification action "Rate app" which takes me to playstore for rating the app.
With a normal intent and using startActivity() from within the app we can handle activitynotfound exception and then take the user to the web url of the app in the broswer. I want to have a similar exception handling with a notification action click.

here's the code snippet

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName());
Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
PendingIntent ratePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestID + 1, goToMarket, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
action = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Action(android.R.drawable.star_on, "Rate me",ratePendingIntent);
```

then i simply set this action on to the notification builder as,
`builder.setAction(action);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using emulator that dosent have google play services.

Make sure you flash google play services.

Comment: yes but any which way, it would be a good practice to catch the exception.

Comment: try catch block would be the simplest and most secure way to implement. But you know its depends how you develop. For example i like that returning code with if control.

Comment: I know this is old, but I'm looking for an answer to the same question.  A try/catch block won't work because the exception won't be thrown until the PendingIntent fires.  All you'd be doing in the try block is setting the PendingIntent.